# How do I identify an entity as a tag in Microsoft Teams context in a bot using botbuilder?

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

In a bot using BotFramework, when I receive a message from a teams channel.
For instance: `@bot say hello to @tagname` when we receive the entities list on the bot this is the structure:

```json
[
    {
        "mentioned": {
            "id": "...",
            "name": "bot"
        },
        "text": "<at>bot</at>",
        "type": "mention"
    },
    {
        "mentioned": {
            "id": "...",
            "name": "tagname"
        },
        "text": "<at>tagname</at>",
        "type": "mention"
    }
]
```

Both my bot and the tag, as also any channel or other user mentioned in the message have the type `mention` and we are not able to identify what kind of entity it is.

This prevents us from knowing how to deal properly with the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `tags` look like, but for bots the id is prefixed with "28:", like "28:[guid]", and for users it's "29:", so that should help. Perhaps check for tags and let us know here in this thread, but I'm pretty sure they'd have their own prefix too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hilton but unfortunately this does not seem to be reliable. In a single test mentioning a couple of different entities I got a tag, a channel and a user all prefixed with "29:".

Comment: oh wow, good to know, I've not seen that - it's been pretty consistent for me I think