# How do I differentiate between a Mention of type [ member | tag | channel ]?

Tags: sdk, botframework, microsoft-teams

`context.activity.entities`  contains an array of Mention objects.
There is no property that identifies Mention type:
Is the object a team member, a tag group, or a channel?

Sending a message to a tag group using the same mechanism as channel, results in the message being sent to the General channel of the team, and not to the members of the tag group.

At present, I can differentiate between users and not users (cahnnels and tags) by checking the id against the list of all team members. This is highly inefficient, as a team could potentially hold 10,000 members.

There are two issues to solve here:

1. Efficient differentiation
2. Retrieving all the members of a tag group

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user3563099, could you please brief the question, can you please explain what is tag group. If you are getting all the values in array , you can change it to json format, there you can differentiate all the values.

Comment: A tag group is a private group that contains team members:
https://www.howtogeek.com/678740/how-to-use-tags-to-manage-group-mentions-in-microsoft-teams/

My major concern is how does my multi-tenanted bot send a message to a tag group?

i.e. a user communicates with my bot and asks that the message be sent to the tag group like this: 

 `@bot send @taggroup "hi guys"`

How does the bot take the @mention Tag Group and send the message to it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT I have a related question, please check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448212/how-do-i-identify-an-entity-as-a-tag-in-microsoft-teams-context-in-a-bot-using-b

Comment: Hi @user3563099, we are debugging the code as you suggested , we will update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

currently bot can @mention user but cannot @mention taggroup. you can raise [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a feature request.

Comment: User voice is for end-users. Anything that is posted there that affects internal architecture, as this does, will never be upvoted, and so this problem will never be solved.